# Batch updating point balances for multiple users

Tags: android-pay, apiary.io

How do I batch update the points balances for multiple Wallet Objects in a single HTTP request.

Comment: Hi, Ameya! I'm sorry but I do not understand your question... Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're still working on a Wallet Objects specific batch tutorials, but for now here's one generic one in Java that should work:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch

Additional languages coming soon and I'll update as we add new tutorials.